# Cannot publish to Queue on ActiveMQ on Linux

Tags: java, linux, activemq-classic

I'm trying to publish a message to a queue on ActiveMQ installed on ubuntu 12.04.
I can publish without any problem to ActiveMQ installed on Windows, but I can't publish on ubuntu. If I create a message from the console, I can consume it.
When I look at the AMQP dump on Wireshark, I see the following message:
"Trying to fetch an unsigned integer with length 42".
Both client and server run on JDK 1.6
Here is my code:

```
public void addMessage(String text) throws Exception {
    TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage(text);
    msg.setStringProperty("odd", "no");
    msgProducer.send(msg);
}

private void init() throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactoryImpl factory = new ConnectionFactoryImpl(host, port, user, password);
    connection = factory.createConnection(user, password);
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination dest = new QueueImpl(queue);
    msgProducer = session.createProducer(dest);
    msgProducer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What does "can't publish" mean? There has to be entries in the log on the broker side (maybe with increased log level) or exceptions/logs in the client. You also need to specify AMQ version.

Comment: I don't see any entries at the log, and I've set the logging level to DEBUG. I'm using AMQ 5.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by copying my working version of ActiveMQ on Windows (5.10.0) to my linux servers (which had version 5.10.1 installed), and it worked. I still don't know what the original problem was...